# trying to update records in 1 data extension from another but

Tags: query, update, marketing-cloud

Users are allowed to retake the online quiz  forms as many times as they wish so we have an update DE  to store them after their initial submission.

[image]

For that they are stored in the original in this case target DE. The  original/target DE stores users based on Subscriber key (emailadress).

[image]

We want to be able to update their DoshaTYPE(1 column) or their Mind/Body status (2 columns). Depending what quiz they take either doshatype will be null or the Mind/Body Fields. We have two separate queries running into the same DE's one checks if Mind/Body fields are null then Doshatype is updated

```
SELECT EmailAddress as SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, DoshaType,  registered_date
from DQNR2
where CurrentMindState is null
and DATEDIFF(Hour, registered_date, Getdate()) = 1
```

Vice Versa. is this the best way to do this? We would like to have the most up to date/latest results updated since the same user can have multiple rows in the update DE.